# Why my flutter app works in debug mode but not after release

Tags: android, flutter, dart, release

I have read some other topics in stackovwrflow with similar problems, But none is answered. So I'm asking here.
I am developing an airhockey game using flutter in android studio. Everything is normal in debbuging mode. But when I build a release version, it's not working correctly.

Maybe this informations help:

I tested the app on a Xiaomi which uses android 4. In that device, sometimes the app will open. but most of the time only a black screen appears and nothing else. (about 70% of the time it fails.)
An other device is a Samsung galaxy J7 with android 8. In that case, the black screen happens more. (about 90%).
The third device is a Xiaomi POCO X3 Pro with android 11. In that case, I could not use the app for just a single time.

The libraries I used are:

```
'package:flutter/services.dart'
'dart:async'
'dart:math'
```

let me know if you need more information.
bye the way you can get code from [github](https://github.com/mohammadpmf/airhockey-flutter) to look in case you need.

Comment: Can you please share full source code?

Comment: Have you added required permissions in the app. release mode requires INTERNET permission for making any network request. for android you can add it in manifest file

Comment: @Rifat Hossain   the full source code is mentioned in the question. It's on github.

Comment: @shaileshmishra   the project does not use internet and it's completely local. and I only changed the default main.dart file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before Fixing**：

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**Please change it to the Following：**

If your `environment sdk: '>=2.x <3.0.0'` you can use the following code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

Future<void> main() async {
  if (window.physicalSize.isEmpty) {
    window.onMetricsChanged = () {
      if (!window.physicalSize.isEmpty) {
        window.onMetricsChanged = null;
        runApp(const MyApp());
      }
    };
  } else {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }
}
```

If your `environment sdk: ^3.0.0` can use the following code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  FlutterView? flutterView = PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.firstOrNull;
  if (flutterView == null || flutterView.physicalSize.isEmpty) {
    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onMetricsChanged = () {
      flutterView = PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.firstOrNull;
      if (flutterView != null && !flutterView!.physicalSize.isEmpty) {
        PlatformDispatcher.instance.onMetricsChanged = null;
        runApp(const MyApp());
      }
    };
  } else {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }
}
```

Comment: Your game design is pretty good, haha

Comment: Thanks @Halifax. The problem has been solved using the code you sent. .

Comment: @Mohammad  Upgrade to Flutter
 In SDK version 3.10.x, it is found that the window.physicalSize method is deprecated.

I updated 2 ways, one is the environment below 3.0.0, and the other is the environment above 3.0.0